# Ansible: Permission denied (publickey, password)

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm not able to connect to a host in Ansible. This is the error:

> 192.168.1.12 | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which
>   will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue",
>       "unreachable": true }

This is my `hosts` file:

```
[test]
192.168.1.12
```

And this is the ad-hoc instruction:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

I'm able to connect via raw `ssh`.

Comment: Is necesary more info, ansible version, and environment, what are u using as hypervisor? virtualbox? vagrant?, at the moment sound like a network problem, send the result of `ansible all -m ping -vvv` ?

Comment: Your question title says "Permission denied (publickey, password)", but the actual error that you quoted says something entirely different. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: @Kenster that error appears when I execute the command with -vvvv option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default Ansible try to use SSH keys. It seems that you have wrong keys. Try to use Password authentication.

`ansible all -m ping --ask-pass --ask-sudo-pass`

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Do you know how can I setup properly ssh keys?

Comment: I have the same problem. And with this tip, I can't to solution it.
$ ansible -i hosts.txt all -m ping --ask-pass --ask-sudo-pass
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The sudo command line option has been deprecated in favor of the "become" command line arguments. This feature will be removed in version 2.9. ...
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 
11.0.0.108 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.", 
    "unreachable": true
}

Answer (score 8):

@bigdestroyer, to setup ssh public keys use this playbook

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    authorized_key_list:
      - name: root
        authorized_keys:
         - key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
           state: present
  roles:
    - { role: GROG.authorized-key }
```

Execute this playbook with `--ask-pass` since you'll use it to setup public key authentication.

`ansible-playbook setup_ssh.yml --ask-pass`

This role will add your current user public key to remote host `authorized_keys` file.

**NOTE**

`ask-pass` works only one time per run so this will only work with hosts that has the same password.

I usually use `-limit` and execute in batches on hosts that has the same password.

For example, let's assume host1,host2 and host3 has password `foo` host4 and host5 `bar`

`ansible-playbook setup-ssh.yml --ask-pass -l host1,host2,host3`

**provide password `foo`**

`ansible-playbook setup-ssh.yml --ask-pass -l host4,host5`

**provide password `bar`**

THEN

`ansible -m ping host1,host2,host3,host4,host5`

You can read the role documentation [here](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/4737)

Comment: I am getting below error when I do what you said above:ERROR! the role 'GROG.authorized-key' was not found in /home/osboxes/roles:/home/osboxes:/etc/ansible/roles

The error appears to have been in '/home/osboxes/setup_ssh.yml': line 10, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - { role: GROG.authorized-key }
      ^ here

Comment: @Techiee, did you installed the role? If not just type: `ansible-galaxy install GROG.authorized-key`.

Comment: [WARNING]: - GROG.authorized-key was NOT installed successfully: Failed to get data from the API serverFailed to validate the SSL certificate for galaxy.ansible.com:443. Make sure your
managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. If the website serving the url uses SNI you need python >=
2.7.9 on your managed machine or you can install the `urllib3`, `pyopenssl`, `ndg-httpsclient`, and `pyasn1` python
modules to perform SNI verification in python >= 2.6. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm
the servers identity but this is unsafe and not

Comment: Looks like the machine you're running ansible doesn't match the python requirements. What version of python you're executing? `python -V`

Comment: I am having Python 2.7.6

Comment: Try to install the modules your warning message is asking for. `pip install urllib3` then: `pyopenssl, httpsclient, pyasn1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125016/discussion-between-techiee-and-bernardo-vale).

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: Well, all you need to do it's install `ansible-galaxy install GROG.authorized-key`. You should recheck ansible [installation process](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html) to make sure every requirement was met!

Answer (score 2):

For those that come here running Ansible 2.6, `--ask-sudo-pass` is now deprecated. The correct syntax is:

```
ansible all -m ping --ask-pass --ask-become-pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue - my ssh keys weren't set up correctly. I fixed this using the following:

- Make sure each machine has an ssh keys set up, using the ssh-keygen command.

  `ssh-keygen`
- Pass your public key over to the machine, using the ssh-copy-id command.

  `ssh-copy-id -i <location of id_rsa.pub> <ip-address of host>`

This helped resolve my error, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding `--ask-pass` argument